# How to replace text in a line with a specifix word using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to update value (unix timestamp) of varible named $buildDate in my config file.

This string looks like

```
// ....
$buildDate='1482327565';
// ....
```

[The official documentation](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) says:

> # substitute "foo" with "bar" ONLY for lines which contain "baz"
>
> sed '/baz/s/foo/bar/g'

I tried to use like this:

> sed -r -e "/buildDate/s/[0-9]{10}/0000000000/g" config.php

But it doesn't work. I get the message "*** forbidden path: /buildDate/s/[0-9]{10}/0000000000/g" instead.

**UPDATE:**
Solved. That's because of my non-root rights.

Comment: I replaced the `-e` with `-i` and it worked as expected.

Comment: `-e ` in GNU sed means "add the script to the commands to be executed" so the token after `-e ` is a path to a file. Remove the `-e`.

Comment: @AvihooMamka the same error

Comment: @LarsFischer this didn't help too

Comment: Your code works fine for me as-is.  This seems like buggy behavior, what version of sed, OS, and shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed '/buildDate/{s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/0000000000/g}' config.php
```

Comment: How is `/pattern/s/old/new/` different from `/pattern/{s/old/new/}`? I don't think it is.